# IIS Express Request Times Increasing Exponentially as SQL Query Takes Longer

Tags: sql, web-services, iis

I have a very strange problem occurred during load testing of my web services. With just single calls it completes very quickly within milliseconds and the SQL call takes about 20 milliseconds. But when I load test with about 290 requests a second the SQL call goes up to about 40 milliseconds but the page return now takes over 8 seconds. What kind of strange relationship is this? CPU doesn't seem to be maxed out.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? What could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Seems this was down to having debug="true" in the compilation section of the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this was down to having debug="true" in the compilation section of the web.config.